# How to get X (number) from a number made by a bit operator (1 << X)

Tags: javascript, bit-fields

Lets say I have something setup like this

```js
var num = 1 << 9 //equals 512
//OR
num = 1 << 6 //equals 64
//OR
num = 1 << 6 ^ 1 << 9 //equals 576
//OR
num = 1 << 6 ^ 1 << 9 ^ 1 << 1 ^ 1 << 8 //equals 834
```

I am trying to take a number, say `834` and put it through a function to reverse it and get all the numbers that made it when I made the left shift value, in this case of `834`, the numbers that made it were 6, 9, 1, and 8.

OR, I want to take the variable `num` and get all the X values in `1 << X ^ 1 << X` and turn it into an array.

So

```js
var values = [0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,17] //this can occur as X in 1 << X
function bitNumberToArray(bitNumber) {
var arr = [];
// what do I put here?
return arr;
}

console.log(bitNumberToArray(834))
//returns [1, 6, 8, 9] *ORDER DOESN'T MATTER*
```

If you are curious in what I'm doing, I'm fetching a user then getting their flag (which is just a bit number) and converting it into something user-friendly like `This user is staff, holds badge X` [on Discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-user-flags)

I have no idea where to start on this, a nudge in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your number to binary and then collect all positive bits' positions like this:

```js
function bitNumberToArray(n) {
    const bits = [...n.toString(2)].map(Number);

    return bits.reduce((result, bit, index) => result.concat(bit ? bits.length - index - 1 : []), []);
}
```

Test:

```js
const test = bitNumberToArray(834);
// returns [9, 8, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the bitwise AND for each bit like this:

```js
var values = [0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,17]; //this can occur as X in 1 << X

function bitNumberToArray(bitNumber) {
  return values.filter(bit => bitNumber & 1 << bit );
}

console.log(bitNumberToArray(834));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the binary representation of the number
834 for example, is equal to 2^9 + 2^8 + 2^6 + 2

```js
function getBinaryRepr(num){
  let repr = []
  while(num > 0){
    repr.push(num % 2) //Parity
    num = Math.floor(num/2) //Integer division
  }
  
  return repr //this is the binary representation of num
}
```

To get those X's from here:

```
getBinaryRepr(num).map((x,index) => x==0 ? x : index)
```

or better than that:

```
getBinaryRepr(num).map(x => x==0 ? x : 2^x)
```

and then simply add them to get the number

Edit: noticed now you don't want the 0's at all, so:

```
getBinaryRepr(num).filter(x => x != 0).map((x,index) => x==0 ? x : index) //or x==1
```

Comment: You don't need to reinvent the wheel with `getBinaryRepr()`. There's built-in `number.toString(2)` doing that.

Comment: Didn't know as I've never really had the need to do this in JS. Good to know though :)